# How to perform arithmetic using chars representing +-*/%

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a simple natural language calculator, and currently have managed to convert all operands into doubles and operators into the chars '+', '-', '*', '/', '%'.

However, I want to evaluate the expression using the correct order of operations, and to that end it would be useful if I could take advantage of Java's natural order of operations when computing expressions. Is there a way to compute this sort of expression that contains character operands? I was thinking that maybe my program could write some sort of temporary java class, compile it and run it to evaluate the expression, but that seems a tad excessive. There must be a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Have you heard about Reverse Polish Notation?

Comment: I've heard of it but I don't know too much about it. How would it be useful in this situation?  Wouldn't I have to parse through the expression to get it into postfix notation?

Comment: You can transform your infix expression into a postfix expression (RPN) (e.g by the recommended Shunting-yard algorithm), then evaluate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to use "Java's natural order of operations", as this is implemented by the compiler, and you're working at runtime. You could use the ScriptEngine to do the whole calculation for you. Otherwise you would have to implement your own expression parser, using say recursive descent, which is pretty easy, or Dijkstra's Shunting-yard algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use ScriptEngine.

Comment: @GaborSch It turns out there was a +6 upvote, whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

The following link shows how can you evaluate math expressions given as String:
[Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

So you can concatenate the operators with double to create mathematical equation String and evaluate using the ScriptEngine as shown in above link. The precedence followed can be changed by using parenthesis appropriately.